What is the particle speed in liquids at an average room temperature (20-25 degrees celcius)?
I've been searching online for ages and I can't find anything related to this, everything seems to be about gas particles relating to temperature. I'm investigating simple chemistry related to collision theory, specifically the increase in likelihood of particle collisions according to increase in acid concentration (between HCl and CaCO3). I want to calculate the probability of a particle collision according to this increase. I already know approximately how many particles of each are present and I had previously tried to calculate using particle sizes (assuming each were roughly spherical or ellipsoid). Although, if anyone knows any better ways to calculate this that would be great, I may be looking in the wrong direction.
For context:
I have 0.03 mol of HCl (30 ml) & 0.01 mol of powdered CaCO3 (1g), therefore roughly 6.0221 x 10^21 CaCO3 compounds, and 1.8066 x 10^22 HCl molecules at an average room temp. Considering two HCl molecules are required to each CaCO3 compound there are 9.033 x 10^21 HCl pairs to 6.0221 x 10^21 single CaCO3 compounds.

Is there an equation to calculate the average speed of liquid molecules?; Do particle velocities in liquid follow the Maxwell-Boltzmann velocity distribution?

Be aware HCl is not present in water solution in form of molecules, but as hydrated ions H+ and Cl- of not well defined hydration sphere radius and  effective mass.

Executive Summary
The answer depends on the liquid and its self diffusion coefficient.
The Details
The Maxwell-Boltzmann distribution of particle speed only applies to ideal gases, though a rarefied gas or plasma may approximate it (BTW, in a plasma, there may be different temperatures for ions and electrons).
In a liquid, the mean free path of a particle is short, so though the kinetic energy and, therefore, speed of the particles follow Maxwell-Boltzmann distribution, the particles don't go very far -- they behave almost as if in a solid, vibrating about a point, but not moving far from it. Think of fruit in aspic. Most collisions, therefore, are with the same neighbor, and do not mix reactants.
Instead, you would be concerned with the self diffusion coefficient, i.e., the rate at which particles diffuse in a system, which is far lower in liquids than the speed of individual particles. This is not as simple as the kinetic theory of gases, throwing in additional factors such as viscosity. This is often determined experimentally, such as the self diffusion coefficients of water, and then from those data points, a curve may be derived, and a kind soul, such as O. Dietrich, might provide an online calculator to interpolate between those points.
So, for a dilute solution in water, you might use that online calculator  to get the speed of diffusion, and calculate the rate empirically.
You might also research the Navier-Stokes equations, which make the opposite simplification from that of the kinetic theory of gases; i.e., a fluid as a continuum, rather than as free particles.
Additional Complication
The reaction $\ce{CaCO3 + 2 HCl -> CaCl2 + H2O + CO2↑}$, with bubbles to stir the solution. This might affect reaction speed, too. sigh
